# Renderscript - why is the type of parameter 'in' a uchar4?

Tags: android, types, parameters, renderscript

I looked at this example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicRenderScript. In that project, they have the following line:

```
mInAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, mBitmapIn);
```

where mBitmapIn is of type Bitmap representing the image to process.
Later, they call the kernel function named saturation in the .rs file asynchronously via an AsyncTask:

```
mScript.forEach_saturation(mInAllocation, mOutAllocations[index]);
```

In saturation.rs file, they have:

```
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) saturation(uchar4 in)
{
    float4 f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(in);
    ...
```

From this thread [Renderscript, what is the `in` parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832030/renderscript-what-is-the-in-parameter) I know that the parameter 'in' points to the data to be processed (which in our case is a pixel, right ? ) So, I know that a pixel consists of 4 color channels and therefore they use **uchar4** which is a vector of 4 uchars (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_value_types.html#android_rs:uchar4 ). But why **uchar** ? Why not, let's say, **uint4** ? Or directly **ufloat4** ??

Answer (score 0):

Renderscript is defined with the C99 standard and lists the `sizeof` values for types here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_value_types

So from that chart:

uchar has a 8 bit unsigned value size

uint has a 32 bit unsigned value size

float has 32 bit size

Android bitmaps are typically configured
[ARGB_8888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888) format so each pixel has 3 color channels along with alpha and those made up of 8 bits.

Even in your example you can see the transformation into floats for computation purposes:

```
float4 f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(in);
```

For a more comprehensive discussion on C type sizes see: [Is the size of C “int” 2 bytes or 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11438794/295004)